# How to delete records with foreign key constraint in mysql single query

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE logins, roles 
FROM logins
INNER JOIN roles ON logins.`LOGIN_ID`=roles.`LOGIN_ID`
WHERE roles.`LOGIN_ID`=25774;
```

> Query: DELETE logins, roles FROM logins INNER JOIN roles ON
>   logins.`LOGIN_ID`=roles.`LOGIN_ID` WHERE roles.`LOGIN_ID`=25774
>
> Error Code: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`foodapp`.`roles`, CONSTRAINT `roles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`LOGIN_ID`) REFERENCES `logins` (`LOGIN_ID`))
>
> Execution Time : 0 sec Transfer Time  : 0 sec Total Time     : 0.038
>   sec

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `ON CASCADE DELETE` constraint setup, you will need to Delete the row from child table first. And, then fire a separate query to delete it from the parent table as well.

```
DELETE FROM roles 
WHERE roles.`LOGIN_ID`=25774;
```

And, then delete from parent table:

```
DELETE FROM logins
WHERE logins.`LOGIN_ID`=25774;
```

From [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html):

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables
>   for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might
>   process tables in an order that differs from that of their
>   parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls
>   back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the
>   ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables
>   to be modified accordingly.

---

If `ON CASCADE DELETE` has been used in the Foreign Key definition, then all you need to do is delete from the Parent table only. It will automatically delete the corresponding rows from the Child table(s).

Comment: @SAHEBG you cannot. Because there is no guarantee in which order the table will be delete. Instead, put `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint in the foreign key definition, and delete from parent table only. Child table rows will automatically get deleted.